# Rails App Performance When Doing Heavy Background DB Updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have searched Google quite a bit but can't find an answer.

I have a data driven application that has the DB constantly updated in the background.

I am constantly writing to the Postgres DB on Heroku. My users hitting the pages that render this data.

I seem to notice that when "Heavy writes" are happening to the DB the application slows dramatically.

**Is there something I can do to make web requests to the DB fast, and make the writes to the DB take lower precedence?** Rails 3.2 application. Updating to 5 soon...

Comment: one way is to make heavy duty db transactions async by pushing them into background jobs using activejob, sidekiq or resque.

Comment: Another option might be to set up a read replica and route user-facing requests there.